# How to invoke the C preprocessor?

Tags: c

How can we invoke the C preprocessor in a C program, like if we want to prepend some of our files to the list of standard library files while using `#include<file_name>` using `-I`, what we should do?

Adding, if we want to add comments to the output of our program, I have heard that we can use `-C` invocation commands. How to do it? Somebody please correct me and explain further if I am wrong.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about...

Comment: ok let me post this link for you..

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html#Invocation

Comment: Though I can understand what is it trying to say, but I really don't know how to implement that in a code. I tried googling but it didn't help. @glglgl

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism you linked to is explicitly *not* to be supposed from within a program, but it is to use the preprocessor for other things, like text libraries etc.

So you can transform a text using the means of the C preprocessor and convert it to its "expanded" form, without compiling it (perhaps it is a configuration file or whatever).

For example, you can have a

`commonpart.h`:

```
[General]
foo=1
bar=2

#define VALUE 3
```

and a

`cfg.tmpl`

```
#include "commonpart.h"
// This is a commet which won't show up in the end
baz=VALUE
```

you can do `cpp -P cfg.tmpl` and thus compile all this to

```
[General]
foo=1
bar=2
baz=3
```

Comment: Thanks, but it would have been more clear with an example.Sorry for bothering, but yeah I do need an example with respect to my concerns of adding comments and normal files.